# Use LDAP for name look up with Oracle Instant Client

Tags: oracle

Partly as a result of having problems with conflicting versions or bitness with the full installation of Oracle client, my development team (of which I'm a member) has been moving towards using [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html) and avoiding the installation on our development machines for most new projects. This has worked out pretty well, even to the point that we deploy to production with this setup. Since we're mostly a .NET shop, we're using the native client (with .NET wrappers), rather than the Java one.

Now a client is requiring that we register the database service with an LDAP server and use the LDAP server for name look up. They have provided `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora` files (and an accompanying encryption config file) that appear to be correct. In particular, the `sqlnet.ora` file does specify LDAP as a possible source for looking up net service names:

```
names.directory_path=(tnsnames,ldap)
```

I am confident that the machine I'm working with can use LDAP to access the service since I was able to do so using SQL Developer (which allowed me to input the LDAP information directly). Assuming they are correct, how can I get Instant Client to recognize this configuration and use LDAP for the name look up?

### What I've tried so far

I have tried setting the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to the directory that contains the provided files, and while this works fine for making Instant Client recognize a `tnsnames.ora` file, it doesn't seem to be enough to get it to start looking at LDAP. Here are the results (with paths, usernames, and passwords changed):

(The following commands happen to be Windows Command Prompt, but I imagine something similar is doable on Linux. The `sqlplus` seen here is the Instant version as well, with accompanying Instant Client binaries in the same directory.)

```
C:\TEMP>SET TNS_ADMIN=C:\path\to\sqlnet\ldap\and\tnsnames\ora\files

C:\TEMP>echo %TNS_ADMIN%
C:\path\to\sqlnet\ldap\and\tnsnames\ora\files

C:\TEMP>sqlplus.exe USERNAME/PASSWORD@LOCALTNSNAME

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jul 7 10:22:25 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Produ
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

C:\TEMP>sqlplus.exe USERNAME/PASSWORD@LDAPTNSNAME

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jul 7 10:24:21 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

### Side note

Are there tags for TNS, LDAP, or Instant Client (or even just normal Oracle Client) that could be added to this question? I couldn't locate any.

Comment: Is it the correct executable? "where sqlplus"

Comment: @BjarteBrandt Yes, it is the one I expect it to be when I run `where` (`C:\TEMP\sqlplus.exe`). To be more specific, `sqlplus` is not "installed" on the machine. It's just sitting in the current directory, with the client binaries beside it. It's definitely picking up on the `tnsnames.ora` file using the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable, since that is off in a completely different directory.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt To confirm it's using the right client binaries, I went ahead and ran `where oci.dll`, too. It also gives the expected result: `C:\TEMP\oci.dll`.

Comment: could be a domain issue. Did you also try with FQ name? (dbname_or_whatever.domainname)

Comment: @ik_zelf I'm not quite sure what the domain for the service would be. The LDAP server is running in the same network as the current machine. Additionally, I've confirmed that the service has the name I expect using SQL Developer. (I can specify all the parameters directly with that, and I'm able to establish a connection and run queries.) You mean `sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD@service_name.domain.something`, right? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Could you post the content of %TNS_ADMIN%\tnsnames.ora, %TNS_ADMIN%\sqlnet.ora and %TNS_ADMIN%\ldap.ora? Instant Client combined with LDAP works from client version 10.1.0.4 onward.

Comment: @ora-600 Sorry, I forgot about this question. It turned out to be problems with the config files themselves, which were provided to us by our client. (Possibly the Kerberos config file; I can't recall off-hand.) What's funny is that I was working in a dev environment trying to do this, it was equally problematic to get it working in staging, and it still isn't working in prod as far as I know. (We ended up using a local TNS name to get the app working.) Definitely wasted money for the project; even if/when it works in prod, the return on investment would be miniscule compared to the cost.

Comment: So did you manage to use LDAP authentication with Instant-Client? We are also using Instant-Client successfully, and getting into Kerberos Auth, it seems it only works with the full (fat) client, not instant-client. Works from  Linux and Windows, but needs okinit on Linux (only part of full-client and server), and works on Windows will full-client as well. We're trying to find a way to support it in instant-client.

Comment: @ddevienne Honestly, I'm of the opinion that LDAP for *connection strings* is more trouble than it's worth. But yes, it worked (in dev and stage). I could not tell you what they changed, though.

Answer (score 2):

Place the `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora` files in your `$ORACLE_ADMIN` directory and make sure to set the environment variables. I made mine the `TNS_ADMIN` directory

(Linux) my .bashrc

```
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/network/admin
export ORACLE_ADMIN=${TNS_ADMIN}

[ku14lts:/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/network/admin]
$ ls
ldap.ora  sqlnet.ora  tnsnames.ora
```

And I was able to connect to a DB not in my `tnsnames.ora`

Answer (score 0):

Using an Oracle 19c instant client, I found it necessary to copy the OH/[network|/mesg]/oraus.ms[bg] files from a 19c server, to the same location in instant client.

The tns files were copied so that tnsping would work, and the ldap files so that LDAP resolution would work.

```
$ ls -l $(pwd)/{ldap,network}/mesg/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 136704 Jul 21 06:20 /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_16/ldap/mesg/ldapus.msb
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 185547 Jul 21 06:20 /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_16/ldap/mesg/ldapus.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba  50688 Jul 21 06:12 /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_16/network/mesg/tnsus.msb
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 259879 Jul 21 06:12 /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_16/network/mesg/tnsus.msg



$ tnsping js01

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-JUL-2023 06:26:34

Copyright (c) 1997, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_16/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used LDAP adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ora11203fs)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=js01)))
OK (0 msec)
```